# Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error:

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2, ionic3, mean-stack

This is my code

```
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class LinkedinPageProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello LinkedinPageProvider Provider');
  }

  //posting facebook data ---------------------------------------
  postFacebookData(fbData) {
    alert(fbData.email);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://192.168.0.100:3000/api/facebookuser',fbData,{headers: headers})

  }

}
```

`app.js` file

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
//app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard dog' }));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/api',users);
```

This is routes js file(`users.js`)

```
router.post('/facebookuser', function(req,res) {
  console.log('facebook request');
```

In my node js console, I'm able to see `facebook request`. data is storing in the database but it is throwing error in front-end console(chrome console)
as

> ERROR HttpErrorResponseerror: ProgressEventheaders:
>   HttpHeadersmessage: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0
>   Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText:
>   "Unknown Error"url: null__proto__: HttpResponseBase defaultErrorLogger
>   @ vendor.js:1823 ErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.js:1884

```
POST http://192.168.0.100:3000/api/facebookuser net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: You don't need to set the header for Content-Type. Angular does this automatically.

Comment: Have you set up CORS to allow your Angular app to connect to your Node app?

Comment: yes, i have setup the cors @Brandon

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove the headers?

Comment: yes i getting same  error

Comment: In your route handler, the pattern is: /facebookuser, but in your Angular app, the POST route is: /api/facebookuser. Do you have an Express (or other) router that is handling the /api portion of the URL?

Comment: yes i m using express for handling api request

Comment: Can you add your complete Angular service class and Express method plus the relevant config (CORS, middleware, etc). It doesn't make a lot of sense that your Angular app would make a successful OPTIONS request to the Express app, then have the POST fail with a connection refusal.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: If you're using the `cors` package from npm, you don't need to redefine it as a separate middleware. Instead, pass it an options object if you need to do something specific. What is `methodOverride()`? If you remove that, does it work as expected?

Comment: In your Angular service, get rid of the headers value altogether.

Comment: yes I have removed them completely now I'm getting error as `HttpErrorResponse`

Comment: You should be seeing two HTTP calls for this post. The first is an OPTIONS request, and then the POST. Which one is failing now?

Comment: Are you able to call this api from Postman or curl?

Comment: I don't know. `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` this is the error i'm facing.

Comment: Test it on Postman to verify this the url you are passing is working?

Comment: or if you are running on node app on localhost, can you try modifying the url to localhost:3000 instead of ip

Comment: I'm running it in the android emulator(b'coz i'm using ionic) I can't connect to the node server using keyword "localhost".